# How to store state on each state update in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Say I have a parent component that renders multiple child components based on an array using .map() method. Using some inputs child component then creates an object which it returns with a callback function on state update.

```
const InputRows = () => {

    const [incomeObj, setIncomeObj] = useState({});

    const fruits= ['apple' , 'orange', 'banana', 'pineapple'];
    
    return (
            fruits.map((fruit, index)=>
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <InputRow fruit={fruit} number={index} setIncomeObj={setIncomeObj}/>
                    </tr>
           )
```

What I need to do now is to store returned objects from all the child components inside one object to then send it out as JSON.

I've tried multiple ways to do it, for example something like using useEffect hook:

```
let combinedIncomeObj = {};

useEffect(() => {
    Object.assign(combinedIncomeObj, incomeObj);
    console.log(combinedIncomeObj);
  }, [incomeObj]);
```

But of course it just replaces existing data in *combinedIncomeObj* on each state update, not adding to it.
Is using state managers like Redux is the only way to achieve my goal? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: why do you want to send object of objects ? when you can sent it as array of objects .

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a dedicated function for this?
You could try this:

```js
const InputRows = () => {

    const [incomeObj, setIncomeObj] = useState({});

    const fruits= ['apple' , 'orange', 'banana', 'pineapple'];

    const onUpdateIncomeObj = (newIncomeObj) => {
       setIncomeObj({
          ...incomeObj,
          ...newIncomeObj,
       })
    }
    
    return (
        fruits.map((fruit, index)=>
           <tr key={index}>
               <InputRow
                  fruit={fruit} 
                  number={index}
                  setIncomeObj={onUpdateIncomeObj}
               />
           </tr>
        )
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid this, you can send adjust the `setIncomeObj` function you pass right in the prop, like this:

```js
return (
   fruits.map((fruit, index)=>
       <tr key={index}>
         <InputRow 
            fruit={fruit} 
            number={index}
            setIncomeObj={(newIncomeObj) => setIncomeObj({
                ...incomeObj,
                ...newIncomeObj,
            })/>
       </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks! But same result here using both solutions: I still only get one object inside incomeObj upon updating

Comment: What is your desired data model? i.e. - why an object of objects and not an array of objects for example?

Comment: As long as it can be converted to JSON - everything goes. But I just can't figure it out for some reason. Even using something as: 
let combinedIncomeObj = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        combinedIncomeObj.push(incomeObj);
        console.log(combinedIncomeObj);
      }, [incomeObj]);
Just replaces the first object in the combinedIncomeObj array on update.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm failing to see your issue. Please have a look at [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-sunset-elof7j?file=/src/Parent.jsx) and let me know if and how it differs from yours so I could adjust accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Send the data as array of objects like this [{ } , { } ]
Just follow the below code

```
const InputRows = () => {

    const [incomeObj, setIncomeObj] = useState([]);

    const fruits= ['apple' , 'orange', 'banana', 'pineapple'];
    const handleIncomeObj = (obj)=>{
      setIncomeObj([...incomeObj,{...obj} ]);
    }
    
    return (
            fruits.map((fruit, index)=>
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <InputRow fruit={fruit} number={index} setIncomeObj={obj=>hanleIncomeObj(obj)}/>
                    </tr>
           )
```

I hope you find it helpful .

Comment: This way I get an error: uncaught TypeError: incomeObj is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add to the object you can use spread syntax

```
let combinedIncomeObj = {};

useEffect(() => {
    combinedIncomeObj = {...combinedIncomeObj, incomeObj}
    console.log(combinedIncomeObj);
  }, [incomeObj]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It still just logs the state of the latest updated component.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I gave up and decided on building out my JSON object from input data upon submit - much easier and kind of makes more sense.